# Tips for getting The Kid in Super Meatboy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

Can anyone help me getting The Kid in Super Meatboy? I can't get past the first mini-level (The one with the 4328796721491672467 spikes).
[image: The guy. WTF]

Comment: Persistence. Good luck!

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'm just waiting for the one guy that'll say "Speed hacks!". But thanks anyway :D

Comment: I think it took me a solid half-hour (and two attempts on the first one!) for each level. It's hard, but it's not impossible!

Comment: @RavenDreamer What do you have?! Sharingan?!!! I'm on this for like what, 4 hours?!

Answer (score 3):

This can probably help you! But you have to do it now!

Comment: I need to do what now?

Comment: I offer you a video that can help you know how to do the level. However, the harder it is to succeed!